# Cabal: Can't install a specific version of the package (with message "only already installed instances can be used")

Tags: haskell, cabal

I've been trying to install some package:

```
PS C:\Users\Neo> cabal install template-haskell-2.15.0.0
Resolving dependencies...
cabal-3.6.2.0.exe: Could not resolve dependencies:
[__0] next goal: template-haskell (user goal)
[__0] rejecting: template-haskell-2.19.0.0, template-haskell-2.18.0.0,
template-haskell-2.17.0.0, template-haskell-2.16.0.0 (constraint from user
target requires ==2.15.0.0)
[__0] rejecting: template-haskell-2.15.0.0 (only already installed instances
can be used)
[__0] rejecting: template-haskell-2.14.0.0, template-haskell-2.13.0.0,
template-haskell-2.12.0.0, template-haskell-2.11.1.0,
template-haskell-2.11.0.0, template-haskell-2.10.0.0,
template-haskell-2.9.0.0, template-haskell-2.8.0.0, template-haskell-2.7.0.0,
template-haskell-2.6.0.0, template-haskell-2.5.0.0, template-haskell-2.4.0.1,
template-haskell-2.4.0.0, template-haskell-2.3.0.1, template-haskell-2.3.0.0,
template-haskell-2.2.0.0 (constraint from user target requires ==2.15.0.0)
[__0] fail (backjumping, conflict set: template-haskell)
After searching the rest of the dependency tree exhaustively, these were the
goals I've had most trouble fulfilling: template-haskell
```

What does the message "only already installed instances can be used" actually mean?

Comment: AFAIK you can't install alternative versions of `template-haskell` because they're hard-wired to GHC releases. If you need an older `template-haskell`, you need an older compiler. — Besides, please only use `cabal install` for installing executables. Leave it to the dependency manager to install libraries, automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like `base`, but unlike most other packages, `template-haskell` is *non-reinstallable*, basically meaning that it's tied to your GHC version and can't be installed, upgraded, or downgraded separately. [Cabal's source code](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/blob/46e822152c9b3f38044870115d7a198b3a509d66/cabal-install/src/Distribution/Client/Dependency.hs#L447-L471) has the full list of such packages. That's what "only already installed instances
can be used" means. (For future readers, newer versions of Cabal say "constraint from non-upgradeable package requires installed instance" instead.)

Ideally, the package you're trying to install should be updated to work with newer versions of GHC, but if you really need to downgrade to `template-haskell-2.15.0.0`, then you can do so by downgrading to GHC 8.8.4. [GHC Boot Library Version History](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/commentary/libraries/version-history) on the GHC Wiki has a table of which GHC version corresponds to which library versions. (Note that there are a lot of GHC boot libraries besides just the non-reinstallable ones.)